# Mass DM to Slack members using JS in browser dev console

Tags: javascript, slack

I have the list of user handles of a Slack Team as a var called storage. I want to send the members DMs en mass by making a JS code that types in to the message form

> /dm @handle test

and sends it.

So far I have managed to code the typing part. Unfortunately I don't know how to "press enter", e.g. submit the typed command. Here is my code:

```
var msg1 = '/dm ';
var msg3 = ' test'

for(var i=0; i<storage.length;i++) 
{

document.getElementsByClassName('ql-editor')[0].innerHTML = '<p>' + msg1 + 
storage[i] + msg3 + '</p>' ;
window.TS.view.submit(); 

}
```

Could you please help me fix the submitting part?

Comment: you prob looking for this guy https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Comment: set a breakpoint on the server-talky-part and look up the stack to see the code invoked by pressing enter, then hop on the chain where it makes sense.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I don't have access to the API. I am a neeeeeeeeeb, dandavis. I don't understand a word of your comment :(

Comment: @neeeeeeeb I dont understand a word of what dandavis said either, im not sure it means anything, depends how hot that chain is :-).... you will need access to the api to send messages i would have thought

Comment: If you have no access to the API, I would check out browser-based user script, which would allow you to automate your user input. check https://tampermonkey.net/

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Thx, checked before I posted here. Unfortunately nothing :/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nothing", but you obv. will have to develop a new user script by yourself. Doubt you'll find finished solutions. Maybe on github...